# обьявить возвращаемый JSON объект в функции и вернуть его

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Как правильно задать тип и вернуть JSON в функции?

```
static func connect(url : String)->JSON<---------{
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                print(json)
                //return json<---------
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Использую Alamofire+SwiftyJson. Пишет, что не правильное возвращаемое значение.Не понимаю как корректно это всё обьявить.

Answer (score 0):

Класс с функцией :

```
class Helpers {
    static let helpers = Helpers()
    static func connect(url : String,completion: @escaping (JSON) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                print(json)
                completion(json)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Класс где вызываем:

```
Helpers.connect(url: "https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=2&limit=20") { (json) in
        print(json)
    }
```